# event listening on child or parent for reacting to changes in siblings

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, web-component, native-web-component

I have created this very common scenario of menu links, in a native vanilla JS web-component format.

```
<side-nav>
    <nav-item id="1">1</nav-item>
    <nav-item id="2">2</nav-item>
    <nav-item id="3">3</nav-item>
    <nav-item id="4">4</nav-item>
</side-nav>
```

Naturally, when I click on any of nav-item, I need to

- make the clicked item active/selected
- check if there is another item already active, and if there is, make that nav-item inactive

With web-components I have observed that I can handle that in two ways.

Method 1:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy1pdju5/)

- dispatch an event when `<nav-item>` gets clicked
- Add an event listener on parent node `<side-nav>`
- on each click event, loop through all child `<nav-item>` components of side-nav and deactivate an already active `<nav-item>` if it is not the  event.target node.

code for `<nav-item>`

```
async connectedCallback() {
    this.addEventListener('click' , (event) => {

        this.setAttribute('selected', true);// immediately mark current component selected

        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('navitem-selected', { bubbles: true, composed: true , detail: { id: this.id} })); // dispatch event, so that parent can loop and deselect other items
    });
}
```

and code for the parent `<side-nav>`

```
async connectedCallback() {

    this.addEventListener('navitem-selected', (event) => {
        let items = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').assignedElements();
        items.forEach((item) => {
            if(item.getAttribute('id') !== event.detail.id) {
                item.removeAttribute('selected');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Method 2:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx3dojm2/)

Completely ignore parent and handle the activation logic only in the `<nav-item>`

```
static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['id', 'selected'];
}

attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if(name == 'id'){
        this.id = newValue;
    }
    if(name == 'selected')
    {
        if(newValue){
            this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.root').classList.add('selected');
        } else {
            this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.root').classList.remove('selected');
        }
    }
}


async connectedCallback() {
    this.addEventListener('click' , (event) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('navitem-selected', { bubbles: true, composed: true , detail: { id: this.id} }));
    });
    const hostNode = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.root').getRootNode().host.parentNode;

    hostNode.addEventListener('navitem-selected', (event) => {
        if(this.id == event.detail.id){
            this.setAttribute('selected', true);
        } else if(this.hasAttribute('selected')){

            this.removeAttribute('selected');
        }
    });
}
```

Both methods work fine but for the life of me I can not figure out which one is better when considering good programming practices and performance.

I have a general concept that child should not know about siblings or parents, but parents should manage children. I am bit blur on the best practices here and would love to be pulled to light.

Comment: I prefer your first option. That's kinda similar to <select onchange="doSth"><option value="" /></select>, where the click event of 'option' is collectively handled in the parent 'select'

Comment: 2nd solution is quite dirty. Also note that in solution 1 you could use standard click event to manage selection

Comment: It depends on the use case. Looks to me like method #2 (after some cleanup) is going to be easier when you want nested ``<nav-item>`` menus. Note: classList has a toggle method and Element a toggleAttribute method

Answer (score 1):

Think of this like you would if it were a set of standard components. Most standard components do not know anything about any other components. So it is the job of a parent component to listen to the events from the child components and make changes to all of the children, as needed.

The only odd-ball component is the `<label>` component with the `for` attribute. You set the `for` attribute to the `id` of the component that will receive focus when you click on the `<label>`. The label that has a `click` event handler and, if there is a `for` attribute it looks for a component with that `id`. If it finds that component then it calls the `.focus()` function on that component.

Doing this your components are not tied together but can connect together.

If I were writing the code I would do it the first way.